# Create valid json file that contains an array of json using json.dump

Tags: python, json

mcve :

```
d1 = {"a":1}
d2 = {"b":2}
import json
with open('test2.json','w+') as file:
     for d in [d1,d2]:
             json.dump(d,file)
```

test2.json content :

`{"a": 1}{"b": 2}`

**Desired Result :**

`[{"a": 1},{"b": 2}]`

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = {"a":1}
d2 = {"b":2}
import json

array = [json.dumps(d) for d in [d1,d2]]
```

Then write array to file

Answer (score 0):

Create a list instead, and dump that list directly.

```
with open('test2.json','w+') as file:
     d = [d1, d2]
     json.dump(d,file)
```

Comment: This is not possible as in actual example in each iteration json object is being generated.
So maybe I've to add those json in list and then finally dump those.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
d1 = {"a":1}
d2 = {"b":2}
import json
tab = [d1, d2]
with open('test2.json','w+') as file:
    json.dump(tab ,file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list and append both the dictionary into list and then write list into the file.

```
d1 = {"a":1}
d2 = {"b":2}
import json
with open('test2.json','w+') as file:
     for d in [d1,d2]:
             list1 = []
             list1.append(d1)
             list1.append(d2)
             json.dump(list1,file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
d1 = {"a":1}
d2 = {"b":2}
import json
with open('test2.json','w+') as file:
    json.dump([d1,d2],file)
```

Answer (score 0):

A list of dictionaries is a json serializable ofject already, so just serialize the whole object you need:

```
import json
with open('test2.json','w+') as file:
    json.dump([{"a":1}, {"b":2}],file)
```